# Can't find the value of an input search

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to edit my search bar so that when the user searches, it automatically adds a wildcard to either side.

The following code almost does the trick, in that it adds the wildcards either side. Unfortunately, it adds them to a blank search term, resulting in '**'. Confused as to why it seems to be unable to find the value of the search input.

Edit: Just to be clear, the issue is that on the site the value of searchfield is coming back as blank, even though the user has entered text.

```js
$('.search-bar').submit(function() {
  var self = this;
  event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;

  var searchfield = $('.search-input');
  searchfield.val("*" + searchfield.val() + "*");

  self.submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/search" method="get" class="input-group search-bar" role="search" style="position: relative;">

  <input type="search" name="q" value="" placeholder="Search our store" class="input-group-field search-input" aria-label="Search our store" autocomplete="off" data-old-term="test">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="submit" class="btn icon-fallback-text">
      <span class="icon icon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="fallback-text">Search</span>
  </button>
  </span>
  <ul class="search-results" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 35px; display: none;"></ul>
</form>
```

Comment: Looks to work properly to me. eg `foo` turns into `*foo*` just before the page gets replaced.

Comment: Looks fine here too

Comment: @certainperformance That's really weird, yeah it works for me too in the snippet but that's copied from the site exactly.

Comment: @Jeto What do you mean? The aim is for the asterisks to appear either side of the search term.

Comment: @SamJohnson I deleted my comment, I thought you were surprised that after searching with an empty text, it would still surround with asterisks. Btw the guy who just answered seemed to believe that too :)

Comment: @SamJohnson You probably just copied the part that you think is relevant to your question, but there is a chance that the part you didn't copy are causing the issue.

Comment: @SamJohnson Go to your browser's console, type `$('.search-input')` and check the number of elements you get. I suspect you have multiple input box with the same class name in your page and you're not getting the `val()` of the input box you're intended to.

Comment: @chanMT That was it! There was a search bar that appears on mobile that used the same class. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

For your this problem:

> Unfortunately, it adds them to a blank search term, resulting in '**'

Just add a check, if input is not empty then only submit and search.

Check below:

```js
$('.search-bar').submit(function() {
  var self = this;
  event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;

  var searchfield = $('.search-input');
  
  if (searchfield.val()) {
    searchfield.val("*" + searchfield.val() + "*");
    self.submit();
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/search" method="get" class="input-group search-bar" role="search" style="position: relative;">

  <input type="search" name="q" value="" placeholder="Search our store" class="input-group-field search-input" aria-label="Search our store" autocomplete="off" data-old-term="test">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="submit" class="btn icon-fallback-text">
      <span class="icon icon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="fallback-text">Search</span>
  </button>
  </span>
  <ul class="search-results" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 35px; display: none;"></ul>
</form>
```

Comment: Hey - that seems to just stop the search from working on my end. The issue seems to be that it's just not able to find the value of the searchfield.

Comment: @SamJohnson this code will work if you will enter some value in `input` field. Yes this could be the case that value is not available but if value will be available then this code will work.

Comment: @SamJohnson did my answer help you? Please let me know

Comment: Not really, but I think the issue was my fault. I think I wasn't clear enough with the issue. Thanks for your help though.